# Magento 2 install to subfolder problem

Tags: magento2, installation

I am installing Magento 2 into a subdirectory beside the main installation. I would like to configure the subdirectory named "test". However, when I try to access localhost/test to enter the setup page, it just tells:

> localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Here is my NGINX config :

```
server {
    listen 80 reuseport;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log ;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log  ;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

    ## Magento Setup Tool
    include conf_m2/setup.conf;

    # Deny all internal locations also default phpmyadmin
    location ~ ^/(app|bin|var|tmp|phpserver|vendor|magento_version|php[mM]y[aA]dmin|pma)/? { deny all; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    ## Static location
    include conf_m2/assets.conf;

    location @static { rewrite /static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last; }
    location @media { try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args; }

    ## Process php files (strict rule, define files to be executed)
    location ~ (index|health_check|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include conf_m2/php_backend.conf;
        fastcgi_cache microcache;
        fastcgi_cache_key $scheme|$host|search|$arg_q;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 2h;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
        fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    }

    ###Here is the directory I want to installed another magento 2, but it now works
    rewrite ^/test /test/$1 permanent;
    location /test {
        try_files $uri /$uri/index.php?$args;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
    rewrite ^/test/admin /test/admin/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: how did u resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no nginx expert but this
`rewrite ^/test /test/$1 permanent;`
suspiciously looks like an endless loop.

Why are you doing this? Just create a subdirectory in `/var/www/` like `/var/www/test` and install Magento there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code in your nginx configuration file.

```
location /test/ {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ rewrite /test /test/index.php?$args;
    expires 30d;
}
```

**OR**

```
location /test/ {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @testhandler;
    expires 30d;
}

location @testhandler {
    rewrite / /test/index.php;
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: proper solution  = installation into its own home directory. no need to change or rewrite anything. just copy nginx config.

Comment: @MagenX Have you tried with adding the **.htaccess** file in your **test** directory? Also, have you checked with adding the `RewriteBase /test/` in your **.htaccess** file as per this https://prnt.sc/q1khla screenshot?

Comment: nginx not working with htaccess. multiple installations into nested folders is a very bad idea...